# What is meant by Projected Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, coherent-states

What is meant by [Projected Hilbert space](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=projected+hilbert+space)? I know almost everything about coherent states. But I don't know the use of projected coherent states. I googled, but I can't find any source.

Comment: There are two very different concepts with the similar-sounding names of "projected Hilbert space" and "projective Hilbert space".  Can you provide more context to clarify which one you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a paper would help to clarify tparkers comment.

The states (kets and bras) of quantum mechanics are elements of the Hilbert space. The Hilbert space has a dimension, e.g the spin of an electron is $S=1/2$, therefore, $m_s= \pm 1/2$ and the Hilbert space is two dimensional.

Suppose we consider an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space and take the projection onto a $m$-dimensional Hilbert space, where $m<n$. Here the projection can be calculated by evaluation the scalar product from all basis vectors of the $n$-dimensional onto the $m$-dimensional Hilbert space, i.e. $<i_n|j_m>$ -- just as in  [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: You are awesome ... I liked the explanation . One more clarification . I heard that projected Hilbert space have some conservation laws. Is that right ?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I don't know if there exists special conservation laws in general. However, you might want to read about the [Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) and how symmetries are related to conservation laws.